# Can I list multiple folders in Google Drive in Search Results if I know their IDs?

Tags: google-drive

If I have a folder with ID (obtained from URL): `ABCD` and I type in the search form of Google Drive:

```
parent:ABCD
```

I get all files & folders that reside in that folder.

However can I do something like `parent:ABCD ids:EFGH,IJKL` and get all files & folders within `ABCD` that have ids of `EFGH` & `IJKL`?

Comment: _(Welcome.)_ Not really. You could try some query but I quite doubt it will work.

Comment: @marikamitsos It took me a while to find out how to say "or" in a search in Google Drive. However it works only for parameters listed in the advanced search form.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any information about searching by file's id, however I made the names unique throughout the specified folder in `parent`, so I can do:

```
(title:("Unique Folder Name 1"|"Unique Folder Name 2")) parent:ABCD
```

So it searches for files & folders that have exactly: `Unique Folder Name 1` **or** `Unique Folder Name 2` in their names **and** they are in parent with id `ABCD`.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Still. I believe you could edit your question because **you mention IDs and not Names of folders**. Also, I think you may have an extra closing parenthesis in your search.

Comment: @marikamitsos My question is about still about IDs as they are guaranteed to be  unique. But decided to add my findings as an answer (& did not mark it as accepted ^^), because it is some kind of a workaround. Removed the extra parenthesis, thank you!

Comment: Just tried it but for some reason it didn't work for me.... :(